# how to see which files are accessed during an application command?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

If I run some command-line application in Linux, how to tell which files were accessed (read and/or written) by that process?  I imagine I would need to place some hooks in the file-system driver and recompile the kernel, or something like that?  Is there an easier way?

Comment: Use [lsof](http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/lsof/) or [fs_usage](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/fs_usage/) perhaps ?

Comment: Why exactly are you asking? What for? What is the concrete use case? Your question is quite broad...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch well, I want to know what this program "needs"

Comment: You'll only know what a *particular run* of your program "needs" !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**strace**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) is a command will display each system call the application makes.

From the man page:

> In the simplest case **strace** runs the specified command until it exits. It intercepts and records the system calls which are called by a process and the signals which are received by a process. The name of each system call, its arguments and its return value are printed on standard error or to the file specified with the -o option.

For instance, each open(), read() and write() operation will show the arguments and the return code.

Comment: yes this is it, I asked "were accessed".  I don't want to race with the process.  the answers only work while the process is running, by starting another command.

Answer (score 3):

You can get list of file access by your application by **lsof** command in linux [Here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/lsof-command-examples/) is list of example

Answer (score 2):

In addition of other answers mentionning `lsof`, `strace` (maybe `ltrace` could be useful too!), `fs_usage` you could use for process 1234 the directory `/proc/1234/`, in particular the *opened* file descriptors are available from `/proc/1234/fd/`; from inside your program you could use `/proc/self/fd/`. See [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

Perhaps [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) or [ptrace(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) is relevant too.